# Inject data into lazy-loaded Mongoid-model before it gets loaded

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am working on a versioning module for Mongoid (Mongoid::Versioning does not suit my needs) and whenever I create an object, I have the option to "go back in time". This works, however as soon as I have has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many, I don't want to eager-load all references.

How can I "inject" a variable into the proxy object before it get's filled with data from the database and handle a callback before creation  (so the user only has to call Object.find(id).atTimestamp(yesterday) once and all the children are automatically at the same state of time?)

Comment: I cross-posted this question on the mongoid mailing list.  Rubish Gupta pointed out a very good article that describes what I want to accomplish:  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/      I have the basic history working, the relations are a problem though

Comment: There was a discussion in mogoid group, but there was no reply. If some thing like that is supported, I guess it can help your use case too. ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/57oN7iPkByo